# can I fit a linear mixed effects models when each participant_ID has different number of data points?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have a question about linear mixed effects models. I want to fit the following:

```
lmer(dep ~ predictor + control + (1|participant) + (1|Test_word), data)
```

in which I have different number of data points (i.e.; Test_word) per participant.
For example:
Participant x has 20 test words
Participant y has 5 test words

How this can affect my model and do I need to worry about it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me (just guessing though) that you should rather use the syntax:

`lmer(dep ~ predictor + control + (1|participant), data)`

Directly to your question: it is not a problem that each participant has a different number of words, if the data are missing at random. Check this out: https://rpsychologist.com/lmm-slope-missingness

Comment: thank you for your answer. I need to use Test word as a random effect as they might correlate between and within participants.

Comment: I see. That does not change my answer though!

Comment: Great! Thank you!